# Loading web role in Azure emulator results in a BadImageFormatException

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that loads fine when I start it directly. When I try to run it vai the Azure SDK's emulator, I get the following exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\62253e0e\13ba4ff3\App_global.asax.a-wnopwm.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

This usually indicates something like a reference to a 64bit assembly on a 32bit system, but I've never seen this error on a ASP.NET project dll. The project configuration is set to AnyCPU. What gives?

Comment: `or one of its dependencies` - as you already noted, referencing different assembly arch. Do you have references to any 3rd parties? I see that you are actually executing on 64bit with 64bit app pool. Is there a chance that you are referencing something that is 32bit (like Microsoft sync framework)?

Comment: I actually think the problem was related to the fact that I had been using VS Performance Analysis tools, which add a post-build assembly processor that adds all the profiler hooks. I'm guessing that process resulted in new 32bit assemblies for the app, which caused the platform conflict. I've not yet had a chance to test on the machine that exibited the problem.

Comment: Interesting observation, which might in fact be true. Please update here, if this is the case.

Comment: I can verify that I was able to run the app on the problem machine after removing the post build assembly info from the system.web/compilation element of the web.config file. This was also causing problems when publishing to Windows Azure (since the assembly only exists on the dev machine with VS installed), so I added a transform to the web.release.config file and all is well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was due to the assemblyPostProcessorType attribute added to the system.web/compilation element of the web.config file when I used VS 2012's performance analysis (profiling) tool. It doesn't appear to clean up after itself very well and the config was left in place, causing an apparently assembly platform mismatch. It also caused problems when publishing to Windows Azure because the post-build assembly wasn't available.

The solution was to add a transform to the web config transform to remove the attribute (assemblyPostProcessorType).

Comment: Could you mark this as Wiki, as this is very useful information.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, exactly.

Comment: There shall be "community wiki" checkbox when you edit the answer. Not sure if that option is available when you answered your own question though ...

Comment: Ahh ok, I was looking for it on the question. Thanks and done.